# CSRF spring implementation without login page

Tags: spring-mvc

I need csrf to be include to my project without a login page. So I just included the following in config xml.

```html
 <security:http >  
        <security:csrf />
 </security:http>
```

I am getting the following error.
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: No AuthenticationEntryPoint could be established. Please make sure you have a login mechanism configured through the namespace (such as form-login) or specify a custom AuthenticationEntryPoint with the 'entry-point-ref' attribute

how can I configure csrf without authentication

Answer (score 3):

This minimum configuration should work:

```
<security:authentication-manager/>
<security:http create-session="stateless" use-expressions="true">
  <security:csrf/>
  <security:http-basic/>
</security:http>
```

Comment: There error was removed. But I couldn't find any change in my application. I am expecting a validation error error since I don't have csrf token in my form.

Comment: Works for me.  Have you added the Spring Security filter to your `web.xml`?

Comment: A working application is available [here](https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-security-csrf).